# Modifying an exisiting meta tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code to remove an existing meta tag to which i dont have access because it is in the solution dll it comes with but basically, I want to remove the meta tag content it comes with to our company content. The problem is that it is not finding the meta tag and I think is because of the way I am setting the `htmlHead = Page.Header`; I think i am missing something there.. but not sure.. This code is in a virtual `Page_Load` in a Base class.

```
    HtmlHead pHtml = Page.Header;

    for (int i = pHtml.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (pHtml.Controls[i] is HtmlMeta)
        {
            pMeta thisMetaTag = (HtmlMeta)pHtml.Controls[i];

            if (thisMetaTag.Name == mName)
            {
                pHtml.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if i am giving the correct rederence to the header since this is in a virtual `Page_Load` in a Base class. Also most of this code was taken from (99%) from here [Code for meta tag removal and replacement](http://www.charlesbryant.com/index.php/88/dynamically-change-meta-tags-in-asp-net/)

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you running? If you're looking to replace the "content" of one of the meta-tags, why remove it and why not just modify the content?

Comment: Yeah that would be good too.., but my issue now is that when i do view source the old meta is rendered along with the new one.. so it is not removing it..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be an issue with the order the events occur. I created a new page in ASP.NET

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="FormMail.WebForm1" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head runat="server">
     <title>Untitled Page</title>
     <meta http-equiv="keyword" name="testy" content="default content" />
 </head>
 <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>

     </div>
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I then used:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string mName = "testy";

            HtmlHead pHtml = Page.Header;

            foreach (HtmlMeta metaTag in pHtml.Controls.OfType<HtmlMeta>())
            {
                if (metaTag.Name.Equals(mName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    metaTag.Content = "Yeah!";
                    break; //You could keep looping to find other controls with the same name, but I'm exiting the loop
                }
            }


            //for (int i = pHtml.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            //{
            //    if (pHtml.Controls[i] is HtmlMeta)
            //    {
            //        HtmlMeta thisMetaTag = (HtmlMeta)pHtml.Controls[i];
            //        if (thisMetaTag.Name == mName)
            //        {
            //            thisMetaTag.Content = "Yeah!";
            //           // pHtml.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
            //        }
            //    }
            //} 

        }

    }
```

When I view the source, I see that the content of the meta tag was modified. Now, you're issue could be that at the time of looping, the control doesn't exist (wasn't added yet) and you're adding it, and then the built in code is adding it.

**EDIT - Suggesting moving code to PreRender incase controls are added after load but before rendering**

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string mName = "testy";

            HtmlHead pHtml = Page.Header;

            foreach (HtmlMeta metaTag in pHtml.Controls.OfType<HtmlMeta>())
            {
                if (metaTag.Name.Equals(mName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    metaTag.Content = "Yeah!";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the code to OnPreRender?  protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e). This is after PageLoad but before the contents are rendered to the browser.

Comment: hmm I will try that the thing is that this is on a PageBase with a virtual Page_Load that gets overriden in other places...

Comment: OnPreRender doesn't depend on Page_Load. They are seperate events. What you're doing is over-riding the OnPreRender to modify the controls prior to render and then calling the base.OnPreRender(e). Any page that inherits from this and over-rides the OnPreRender should also call "base.OnPreRender(e)" just like the sample code I gave you so that it bubbles up.

Answer (score 2):

Though this is a old thread, I thought to share a LINQ based approach to select the HtmlMeta control from the Page controls collection:

```
HtmlMeta htmlMetaCtrl = (from ctrls in page.Header.Controls.OfType<HtmlMeta>()
                                     where ctrls.Name.Equals("keywords", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                     select ctrls).FirstOrDefault();
            if (htmlMetaCtrl != null)
                htmlMetaCtrl.Content = metaContent;
```

The following generic fuction can be used for changing the meta tags dynamically:

```
    public class WebUtils
{
    public static void SetPageMeta(string metaName, string metaContent, HttpContext httpContext = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(metaName))
            return;

        if (metaContent == null)
            throw new Exception("Dynamic Meta tag content can not be null. Pl pass a valid meta tag content");

        if (httpContext == null)
            httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        Page page = httpContext.Handler as Page;
        if (page != null)
        {
            HtmlMeta htmlMetaCtrl = (from ctrls in page.Header.Controls.OfType<HtmlMeta>()
                                     where ctrls.Name.Equals(metaName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                     select ctrls).FirstOrDefault();
            if (htmlMetaCtrl != null)
                page.Header.Controls.Remove(htmlMetaCtrl);

            htmlMetaCtrl = new HtmlMeta();
            htmlMetaCtrl.HttpEquiv = metaName;
            htmlMetaCtrl.Name = metaName;
            htmlMetaCtrl.Content = metaContent;
            page.Header.Controls.Add(htmlMetaCtrl);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Web page handler context could not be obtained");
        }
    }
}
```

This can be called from OnPreRender from the User Controls (ascx controls) or Page_PreRender from the Page (aspx):

```
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
    WebUtils.SetPageMeta("keywords", "Your keyword, keyword2, keyword3");
    WebUtils.SetPageMeta("description", "Your page description goes here...");
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, do this:

```
HtmlHead pHtml = Page.Header;
```

instead.  Creating a new HTML header won't exactly work well; instead just assigning the header will work much better.  Just make sure an existing:

```
<head runat="server"></head>
```

exists on the page, either in the master page or on that page.

Comment: hmm yeah weird i changed the code , what it is doing now is, it is putting the new meta tag but the old one is still there..

Comment: @user710502 then you may want to put a breakpoint in and see what's going on; most likely, the matching part isn't working as expected for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove meta tag in coding site then use following code

```
Dim meta4 As New HtmlMeta()

    meta4.Name = "AUTHOR"
    meta4.Content = "AUTHOR"
    Me.Page.Header.Controls.Remove(meta4)


    Dim meta5 As New HtmlMeta()

    meta5.Name = "DESCRIPTION"
    meta5.Content = "DESCRIPTION"
    Me.Page.Header.Controls.Remove(meta5)



    Dim meta6 As New HtmlMeta()

    meta6.Name = "KEYWORDS"
    meta6.Content = "KEYWORDS"
    Me.Page.Header.Controls.Remove(meta6)
```